# Posting to IP using ajax not working in Cordova but works fine with phone browser

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova, ip

I am trying to post data to my computer IP(as the url) in cordova. I can access the IP from my phone and even test the cordova app with the phone browser. The phone browser works perfectly.
When I run the app in my android phone(Android 9.0), it falls to an error(Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'myIP'.

This is my code;

```
$.ajax({
            url: "http://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:8000/arat", 
            data:{
                password:password,
                studentID:studentID
                },
            type:'post',
            //dataType: 'xml',
            async: false,
            contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            success: function(result){


                    alert("Data: "+result);

            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){

            alert("msg: "+thrownError+" , status: "+xhr.status);
            }
    });
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is it an IP thing, tried like every possible thing. Anyone out there with a work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an SSL issue with android 9; had to add xml:android to widget as follows;

```
<widget id="my.app.cordova" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

Then add added the following platform;

```
<platform name="android">
  <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
      <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
  </edit-config>
</platform>
```

Thank me later.